# Compare and display 4 numbers ascending using min(a,b) and max(a,b)

Tags: c++

```
f = min(min(a,b),min(c,d));
l = max(max(a,b),max(c,d));
ma = ?
mb = ?
```

so, the first one and the last one is obvious, but how do I know which numbers are in the middle?

Comment: The ones in the middle are the ones that aren't on the ends. Think about how you'd do this without a computer.

Comment: There are a very small amount of combinations of these two functions it should take very little time to figure out which ones do what you need

Comment: 4 things can be ordered 4!=24 different ways.  That means you need 5 bits of info (2^5=32>24>2^4=16)  to find the right ordering.

Answer (score 4):

A very lazy way to find the second highest of four numbers is by computing the maximum of all possible triplets and then the minimum of those results

```
min(max(a,b,c),max(a,b,d),max(a,c,d),max(b,c,d))
```

And for the second lowest you do the opposite

```
max(min(a,b,c),min(a,b,d),min(a,c,d),min(b,c,d))
```

It is now straightforward to write this down in combinations of `min(a,b)` and `max(a,b)`.

The reason why this works is that in the four possible triplets, three triplets will contain the maximum value and one triplet not. The maximum of the latter triplet will hence give the second highest value while the first three will result in the highest value. Taking the minimum of those four values will give you the second highest value of the quadruplet.   Assume `c` is the highest value and `a` the second highest

```
 max(a,b,c) = c
 max(a,b,d) = a
 max(a,c,d) = c
 max(b,c,d) = c
 min(c,a,c,c) = a
```

An identical reasoning holds for the second lowest number

Answer (score 1):

You can break them into groups of 3 and do min/max on the groups and then the reverse operation on the result. I've shown in the code what the part results will be.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    int a=2;
    int b=1;
    int c=4;
    int d=3;

    std::cout << std::min({a,b,c,d}) << "\n";
    std::cout << std::max({std::min({a,b,c}), std::min({a,b,d}), std::min({a,c,d}), std::min({b,c,d})}) << "\n";
    //                        min->    1                  1                2                  1
    //                        max->                                        2
    std::cout << std::min({std::max({a,b,c}), std::max({a,b,d}), std::max({a,c,d}), std::max({b,c,d})}) << "\n";
    //                        max->      4                  3                4                  4
    //                        min->                         3
    std::cout << std::max({a,b,c,d}) << "\n";
}
```

But using min/max for this seems inefficient since the same elements are being compared many times whereas std::sort is likely to use [quicksort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) with an average of O(n log n) comparisons. I'd therefor use sort to get the values in order. Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>


int main() {
    int a=2;
    int b=1;
    int c=4;
    int d=3;

    std::array A{a,b,c,d};
    std::sort(A.begin(), A.end());

    for(auto v : A) {
        std::cout << v << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: "Seems inefficient" is not argument enough. Can You prove it?

Comment: Updated my answer, but I haven't actually measured the performance. There is of course some overhead in creating the vector that may prove my alternative performing worse than the min/max approach.

Comment: vector + sort more efficient? [you should benchmark first](http://quick-bench.com/ioQQRolrIJLaGLzD0YT-hIp52jw). Dynamic allocations are expensive.

Comment: StackOverflow just informed me I can't upvote your comment more than once, @Borgleader. Seems like a bug :)

Comment: Big-O notation is useful for describing how computation increases as input size increases, but no help at all for comparing algorithms when _n_ is small.

Comment: No need for `std::vector` - it's much more efficient just to sort an array: `std::array v{a,b,c,d};
    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());`

Comment: @Borgleader Cool. I added some random noise to the [benchmark](http://quick-bench.com/xuvgFjF9JqDCJmYVbJC1J7tntWs) and then it became a little more even but clear that array+sort is faster.

Comment: Updated it to exclude the vector and using an array instead. `std::sort` still seems to outperform the min/max version - but if one created specialized min/max versions for 3 and 4 elements, the result may be different.

Comment: It's a lot less even if you [don't benchmark the random number generation](http://quick-bench.com/lYOdmaTx8rB2-KEl81Se7orvXO8) (vector vs others that is)

Comment: @Borgleader Yes, that made it clearer, thanks. I tried a plain C style array too but didn't gain anything by doing so